# replacing HTML in a div using $.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am running a jQuery ajax method, and on succcess (.done) I am wanting to load in some HTML so that the users gets some updated figures on their profile.

The HTML I am trying to replace looks like this,

```
<div id="large_buttons"><a href="">Button</a><a href="">Button 2</a></div>
```

To this I am doing the following,

```
$("#large_buttons").load(site_url+"my_profile #large_buttons");
```

However this just creates the following HTML,

```
<div id="large_buttons"><div id="large_buttons"><a href="">Button</a><a href="">Button 2</a></div></div>
```

What I am wanting to is load my new HTML totally overwrite the existing `#large_buttons` div

is this possibe?

Comment: Can you post what you have and what would you like to achieve ?

Comment: This is exactly what I have and what I want to achieve, I want load #large_buttons from an alternative URL and overwrite the existing #large_buttons

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood your question, it's not very clear...

Comment: I have edited my question, this hopefully makes my aims clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (as you've seen) loads the response directly into the specified element, so one solution is to change your server-side code to only output the content without the #large_buttons div itself.

The other solution is to use one of the other [Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), e.g., the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and put the returned html exactly where you want it from within the success handler:

```
$.get(site_url+"my_profile", function(data) {
    $("#large_buttons").replaceWith(data);
},'html');
```

(In theory you do't need the last parameter to indicate the datatype because jQuery makes an "intelligent guess", but it can't hurt to explicitly tell it you're expecting html.)

The [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) does exactly what it sounds like it should do.

EDIT: I just noticed (as pointed out by Jon) that you were using the syntax of `.load()` where you include a selector for which part of the returned html to use, so you could simply modify that selector to take the elements in the response that are inside the #large_buttons div:

```
$("#large_buttons").load(site_url+"my_profile #large_buttons > *");
```

Should work with your sample html where the div contains only other elements and not text nodes.

Comment: AFAIK `$.get` does not respond to the `#large_buttons` part, so this approach will require server-side modifications as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, yes, I just noticed that. But as per my edit that probably means a minor tweak to the selector passed to `.load()` will do the trick without any other changes.

Comment: +1, that's an interesting approach as well (although I don't like any approach with `.load`'s filtering to be frank).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace `div#large_buttons` with a new version that you get from the server. JQuery's [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the least amount of changes to your existing code, then the simplest would be to wrap `#large_buttons` inside another element (where it will be an only child) and simply use `.load` on that one.

You would not need to do this if you forfeited `.load` and gone with more basic functionality like `$.get`, for example:

```
$.get(large_buttons_url, function(data) {
    $("#large_buttons").replaceWith(data);
});
```

...but then you lose the automatic DOM filtering that `.load` can do (you can no longer append `#large_buttons` to the URL), so you have to make sure that the AJAX request *only* returns the HTML fragment you are interested in.

Personally that's what I would do as it doesn't sound very nice to fetch the whole page and discard all but a part of it; but again, this will require you to modify more code than the alternative.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Load replaces the *contents* of the selected element. You either need to use load on a wrapper div, or change the structure of the div you're loading.

Answer (score 0):

to load some content using ajax to any of your div, you can use `jQuery load` function

```
$("#large_buttons").load("url_which_Returns_html.php",function(data){
   alert("Items loaded");
});
```

This will load the content(overwrite existing content) returned from php page to the div with id "large_buttons"

If you want to load the data after a purticular div, you can do like this

```
$.get("url_which_returns_html.php",function(data){
   ('#right').after(data);
});
```

This will load the response from the php page to after the div with id "right"